# Unknown Custom element laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am getting this error when I try to do post request with the vue

My app.js

```
Vue.component('comment', require('./components/Comment').default);
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   store
});
```

My Comment.vue

```
    <template>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md col-md-12">
                   @comments(['model'=>$book])
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </template>

     <script type="text/javascript">


export default {
            props: ['book'],
            mounted() {
                console.log('Mounted');
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    message: '',
                };
            },

            methods: {
                formSubmit(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    let self = this;

                    axios.post('comments', {
                        message: this.message,

                    })
                    .catch( (error) => {
                        flash("Something Went Wrong", "danger");
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and I have used this component in this page called review.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
    <comment></comment>
</div>
```

But is is giving me the error in the console Do I have to give the name to the component or what .I cant understand this problem

```
vue.common.dev.js:630 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: 
<comment> - did you register the component correctly? 
For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some Blade syntax inside your template:

```
<div class="col-md col-md-12">
    @comments(['model'=>$book])
</div>
```

If this does not fix your problem than you might want to check when you load your `app.js` file or load the component locally for the Vue instance:

```
import comment from './components/Comment';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    components: {
        comment
    }
});
```